# basic matlab, something wrong with my code

Tags: matlab

I've tried working around this but couldn't figure out whats wrong.
see this code:

```
f=50;
w=2*pi*f;
x=[1:0.1:10];
y=240.*cos(w.*x)
```

the y variable is of size 1x91 double, min = 240 and max = 240.. it is all 240s
what i am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 4):

`w .* x` = `pi * 2 * f * x` = `pi * 100 * x`.

`x` only has one decimal place. This means `100 * x` Will all be integers. Meaning `w.*x` will result in integer multiples of `pi`. The `cosine` values at integer multiples of `pi` is 1, resulting in all 240s.